# Columns and rows not aligned correctly

Tags: html, css, angular

I am creating a html table in angular application which has rows populated dynamically. The columns are static content as seen in the code shared below. I have applied some styles but that is still not correcting the problem. Could somebody tell me where I am going wrong ?

As you can see in the screenshot below Accounting Class Name column takes the entire width of the table.

Html

```
<style>

    th,
    td {
        padding: 7px;
    }

    .fundClassesTable {
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-size: 11px;
    }

    .tableItem {
        text-align: center;
        border-left: solid 1px lightgrey;
        border-top: solid 1px lightgrey;
        border-right: solid 1px lightgrey;
        border-bottom: solid 1px lightgrey;
        width: 100px
    }

    .rowItem:hover {
        background-color: #f5f7f7;
    }

/*
    tr {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
th, td {
  display: block;
}
    */




</style>


<div *ngIf="FundClasses && FundClasses.FundDetailsViewModel">

    <table class="fundClassesTable" >

        <tr>
            <th class="tableItem bold">Accounting Class Name</th>
            <th class="tableItem bold">Class ID</th>
            <th class="tableItem bold">Legal Fund Class</th>
            <th class="tableItem bold">Inception Date</th>
            <th class="tableItem bold">Invested Amount</th>
            <th class="tableItem bold">Vehicle Type</th>
            <th class="tableItem bold">Closure Status</th>
            <th class="tableItem bold">Is Side Pocket?</th>
            <th class="tableItem bold">Is Thematic?</th>
            <th class="tableItem bold">Cogency Class?</th>
        </tr>

        <div *ngFor="let fundClass of FundClasses.FundDetailsViewModel" >
            <tr *ngFor="let f of fundClass['FundClassDetailsViewModel'] | keyvalue">
                <td class="tableItem">{{ f.value.Description}}</td>
                <td class="tableItem">{{f.value.Id}}</td>
                <td class="tableItem">{{ f.value.LegalFundClassId}}</td>
                <td class="tableItem">{{f.value.InceptionDate}}</td>
                <td class="tableItem">{{ f.value.InvestedAmount}}</td>
                <td class="tableItem">{{f.value.ClosureStatusId}}</td>
                <td class="tableItem">{{ f.value.VehicleTypeId}}</td>
                <td class="tableItem">{{f.value.IsSidePocket}}</td>
                <td class="tableItem">{{ f.value.IsThematic}}</td>
                <td class="tableItem">{{f.value.CogencyClassId}}</td>
            </tr>
        </div>


    </table> 


</div>
```

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: I think the div might be the problem here

Comment: Yes, <div> is the problem here.

Comment: What do I do to fix this?

Comment: @Tom Share a demo code on stackblitz.com to get a quick solution

Comment: here is the stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nejjib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ng-container` instead of the `div`, it won't add an extra element to the DOM.

```
        <ng-container *ngFor="let fundClass of FundClasses.FundDetailsViewModel" >
            <tr *ngFor="let f of fundClass['FundClassDetailsViewModel'] | keyvalue">
                ...
            </tr>
        </ng-container>
```